# Differences in Abstract Base Class creation methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, metaclass, method-resolution-order

These are different methods to create a Abstract Base Class and register it to a concrete class:

### Imports:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import ABC
from abc import abstractmethod
```

### Method 1:

```
>>> class A(metaclass=ABCMeta): 
...     @abstractmethod
...     def hello(self):
...         return
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def hello(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.hello()
Hello World!
>>> 
>>> print(B.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

### Method 2:

```
>>> class A(object): 
...     __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
...     
...     @abstractmethod
...     def hello(self):
...         return
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def hello(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.hello()
Hello World!
>>> 
>>> print(B.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

### Method 3:

```
>>> class A(ABC): 
...     @abstractmethod
...     def hello(self):
...         return
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def hello(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.hello()
Hello World!
>>> 
>>> print(B.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'abc.ABC'>, <class 'object'>)
```

### Method 4:

```
>>> class A(metaclass=ABCMeta): 
...     @abstractmethod
...     def hello(self):
...         return
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def hello(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> A.register(B)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.hello()
Hello World!
>>> 
>>> print(B.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

### Method 5:

```
>>> class A(ABC): 
...     @abstractmethod
...     def hello(self):
...         return
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def hello(self):
...         print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> A.register(B)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.hello()
Hello World!
>>> 
>>> print(B.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

## Questions:

1. Apart MRO, what's the difference between them?
2. Does they have different usage cases?
3. Is there a preferred or more pythonic way to do it between them?

PS: note that only #2 works also in Python 2

Comment: I think you are confusing "metaclass" with "abstract base class".  Method 1, for example, *uses* the metaclass `ABC` to create an abstract base class `A`.

Comment: You're very right, corrected.

Comment: That said, methods 3 and 5 are a bit weird, in that in each you make `A` another metaclass by inheriting from `ABC`, rather than *using* `ABC` as the metaclass.

Comment: It seems `ABC` was created to be used this way: `With this class, an abstract base class can be created by simply deriving from ABC, avoiding sometimes confusing metaclass usage` https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC

Comment: My bad; I haven't moved to Python 3 yet, and was just mentally substituting `ABCMeta` for `ABC`.